# Possible Apache throttling HTTP requests

Tags: apache, plesk

I have Apache running on CentOS and I was wondering if there is a specific setting in httpd or otherwise whereby there is a timeout period for multiple requests from the same IP.

I am developing on the server, and hence I'm doing a lot of page loads when I keep refreshing the page to check my work. I frequently get 504 time outs, or it takes ages to return the page, but then other times it is lightning fast. Its usually really fast when I leave it for a bit (for the first few page loads, then it times out again).

I'm sure that this is an inbuilt/default setting to prevent loads of requests from one client, but its incredibly frustrating to me when I am trying to develop!

I am running Plesk on Apache, which I guess could also be throttling me?

Any clues or hints greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not on the standard apache modules, and not (AFAIK) on the modules which ship with Centos. That you are getting a 504 error implies that the timeout is occurring with the request on Apache (rather than on a firewall in front of apache). Is this static content?

> I am developing on the server

Bad idea to use you production system for development / testing. This also implies that the page is generated from a script - it's more likely your script is at fault. Try profiling it.

> I'm doing a lot of page loads

Really? you probably need to spend some time thinkig about your code, and how you develop your code.

Comment: I know its not the best way to work. I'm nearing the end of this particular project so I won't change this time, but I definitely will next time. Thanks for the info on standard modules.